# Only `inventory_cleanup_reservations` CRON is not scheduled

Tags: magento2.3, inventory, magento-cron

The `Magento2.3` instance is installed in AWS server. The CRON has setup correctly and there are many CRON's running successfully. Below is the content of `cron_schedule`.

[image]

But the issue is CRON with `job_code` `inventory_cleanup_reservations`. This CRON has never been scheduled since the installation. Which is causing an issue in stock management in case of the abandoned order. The `inverntory_reservations` tables is never been cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is causing the lack of scheduling, but as a workaround until you find a final fix, you can run the cron individually as a command or add it as a filesystem cron.

1. Install the N98 Magerun tool for Magento 2 https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2.
2. Run the command:

```
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run inventory_cleanup_reservations
```